# Polymorphism in MongoDb and ASP.NET Core - System.InvalidOperationException : The property 'Advertise.CarModel' could not be found

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have these classes:

```
public class Advertise
{}

public class HouseAdvertise : Advertise 
{
    // props
}

public class CarAdvertise : Advertise 
{
    public string CarModel { get; set; }
}
```

I created this in the database context:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Advertise>().ToCollection(CollectionNames.Advertise);
modelBuilder.Entity<CarAdvertise>().ToCollection(CollectionNames.Advertise).HasDiscriminator<string>("Discriminator");

// and other subclasses
```

I got an error in this code:

```
var Advertises = DatabaseContext.Advertises.ToList();
```

> System.InvalidOperationException : The property 'Advertise.CarModel' could not be found. Ensure that the property exists and has been included in the model

How should I solve this problem?

Comment: This looks like the ef core is trying to include all properties form the derived classes. When you are using the Advertises, since Advertises has two class. So if you want to query, you could try this `DatabaseContext.Advertises.OfType<CarAdvertise>().ToList()`.

Comment: @BrandoZhang  I tried it, although it didn't work, Thanks, I think the problem is all of them being saved in the same `Advertises` collection, I don't know how to resolve it though....